# Unable to paste html inside a textarea in vue js

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

Here is the text I have from my axios response:

```
this.text = "hello there, this is my name\nHow are you?"
```

I am unable to paste this.text inside my textarea and have the html behave as "html" and not as text. Right now the \n shows up as "\n" and not as a visual break line.

```html
<textarea v-model="text">{{text}}</textarea>
```

I would have thought it was easy but cannot find an answer to it.

Comment: Have you tried setting the value of `message`  to `text` , rather than trying to put it in the html area between the tags?

Comment: @Benny I [cannot reproduce that](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-h6m3bg?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fmain.js).

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake in my post, I changed it, based on what others told me(outside of stackoverflow), the only way is to use v-html and not v-model.